# Reset and sync origin/master to upstream/master (since my pull request was discarded)

Tags: git, github

I made a change to a forked repo, pushed it to origin/master and submitted a pull request. The pull request was not accepted. How do I reset my changes *and* sync to the latest from upstream/master to  my local repo and my github origin/master repo

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git clean -f -d
git push origin master --force
```